# How do people organize project and project tests in one git repo in visual studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, github

So I'm new to Visual Studio and C#. I've started a project. Wishing to use NUnit, I follow some instructions and start another project (in the same solution). Now, when I push to github, I only get the non-test project. Now I see the project and the test project are two separate folders, two separate git repos. Is this how people usually set up their solutions? I'd really wish I could have project, NUnit test-project, all under one umbrella, all of it push-able to github. Is this possible? Is this a bad idea?

Comment: Sure you can have it all in the same Git repo. Why didn't you set it up like that if that's how you wanted it?

Comment: Look at popular projects on GitHub and see how they set up projects. Then pick the style you like the most. There is really no guideline on this, you can just do whatever you like.

Answer (score 1):

Make a folder where your solution file is saved.
Create subfolders for your projects and test projects.
Make a single git repo in the directory of your solution file and add the subfolders of all your projects (including test projects).
That would be one possible way to fullfill your request.